# What is knet interface and what is it used for?

Tags: linux

Can some expert please throw some light on what is knet interface and what is it used for.
One of my container images show knet2 as an interface for output of 'ifconfig'
I have no idea what it is, can someone please explain or point me to documents / web where I can find more about it.

Answer (score 0):

knet is kernel network interface for efficient of packet exchange between switch and the kernel (linux operating system) network protocol stack.

There could be other methods which could used, such as implementing a software connector module over the Open NSL Rx/TX APIs.

Answer (score 0):

> The intent of theknet interface is to provide a network interface that
>   then delivers packets to the NetIO framework from the kernel.

this is nicely explained in [user-networking.pdf](http://mcrae.homeunix.net/papers/user-networking.pdf). 
I hope this is what you were expecting. feel free to comment for any clarification.

Comment: The pdf is not accessible.

Comment: 'A User Level Networking Infrastructure for Linux by Andrew McRae (amcrae@netd.com) NetDevices Inc' is name of paper. google it. one other link is https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/108f/c8287224e38c291ded19c4b944f52ec87ff5.pdf

Answer (score 0):

this is about knet reference

- This module implements a Linux network driver for Broadcom
- XGS switch devices. The driver simultaneously serves a
- number of vitual Linux network devices and a Tx/Rx API
- implemented in user space.
- 
- Packets received from the switch device are sent to either
- a virtual Linux network device or the user mode Rx API
- based on a set of packet filters.susp
- 
- Packets from the virtual Linux network devices and the user
- mode Tx API are multiplexed with priority given to the Tx API